# .class error in java applet

Tags: java, applet

I am writing an applet that will randomly pick 10 cards and show them on the screen. However, I am receiving a .class error and a ; needed error when I attempt to pass an String[]. Anyone help?  This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

public class unit12Assignment extends Applet
{
Image card1 ... card52;

public void init()
{
    card1 = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c1.gif" );
    ...
    card52 = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "sk.gif" );
}

public void getCards()
{
    String cardNumber; 
    double cardRandom;
    int cardRandomNumber;
    String[] cardSelection = new String[10];
    Random ran = new Random();

    for (int number = 0; number <=  9; )
    {
        cardRandom = ran.nextInt(52) + 1;
        cardRandomNumber = (int) Math.round( cardRandom );

        if ( cardRandomNumber > 0 && cardRandomNumber <= 52 )
        { 
            cardNumber =  "card" + cardRandomNumber;
            number++;
        }
    }   
    paint( String[] cardSelection );
}

public void paint(Graphics g, String[] card)
{
    setBackground( Color.green );
    g.drawImage( card[0], 10, 10, this);
    g.drawImage( card[1], 90, 10, this);
    g.drawImage( card[2], 170, 10, this);
    g.drawImage( card[3], 250, 10, this);
}
```

}

Comment: In the 3rd millennium, we generally use `JApplet` over `Applet` for many reasons.  A prime reason here would be 'double buffering'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
paint( String[] cardSelection );
```

should syntactically be

```
paint( cardSelection );
```

You only need to write the type (for example `String[]`) before a variable when you first declare it. From there it can just be referred to by its name.

I also notice that `paint` takes a `Graphics` argument as well as a `String[]`, so you'll need to pass that in as well:

```
Graphics g = getGraphicsSomehow();
paint(g, cardSelection);
```

**EDIT:** see [Andrew Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327416/697449) for a disclaimer on using `Graphics` with an alternative solution.

Comment: The paint method signature calls for two parameters: `public void paint(Graphics g, String[] card)`. Wouldn't he need to pass a parameter for the `Graphics` param?

Comment: Just changed it and that seems to be a problem as well. Never learned how to use it only that its there. You answered my question however. Thanks!

Comment: `Graphics g = getGraphicsSomehow();`  (shudder)  See my answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Very interesting - I personally have no experience with swing so thanks for flagging that.

Comment: It applies to both Swing and AWT.  Or rather, most painting at this level is (from the package of) AWT.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Anything involving `getGraphics()` is a fragile solution.

If the user drags another another app. over the browser and covers the applet, then minimizes the other app., it is likely to erase the custom painted pixels.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
for how to paint correctly (which breaks down to 'paint when told to do so').

An alternative is to use a `BufferedImage` for the rendering and display it in a `JLabel`.  Paint to the image whenever required, then repaint the label.